# Moment.js Date validation DD-MMM-YYYY

Tags: javascript, validation, momentjs

I expect this to return true, but instead it returns false.

```
moment("01-Jan-2020", "DD-MMM-YYYY", true).isValid()//returns false (I expect it to return true)
```

How can I strictly validate this format("DD-MMM-YYYY") using Moment? I need strict mode enabled because I want to validate specific seperators.

Comment: The third arg is locale; strict mode is the fourth arg: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/

Comment: I ran this in the console: `moment('01-Jan-2020', 'DD-MMM-YYYY', true).isValid()
true`

Comment: @Pat: Your code evaluates to `true` for me. Not sure why you're seeing otherwise.

Comment: I am using moment version 2.11.0

Comment: For my console it is spitting out false

Comment: Can you upgrade moment? Works correctly with the latest version.

Comment: @ericgio I tried passing in true as the fourth argument and it is still not making a difference

Comment: Problem is with parsing the month, not sure why

Comment: I've just tested this code on momentJs versions 2.11.0 and 2.29.0, and the old version returned `false` while the new version returned `true`. Seems like a bug in the old version. May be related - https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/3126

Comment: This looks like a bug specifically in 2.11.0. Both 2.11.1 and 2.10.6 work.